# How do I allow that a certain class can be accessed only once inside a python script?

Tags: python, class, input

I have some code with several classes. During the execution, I want that some of them could be accessed only once by the input from the user although they could potentially be more than once.

Here is my code:

```
import sys

class Type:

    def question1(self):
        return 'Question 1: 5 + 5 = ' + '(For lifelines 1, 2 or 3 type the number.)'
    
    def answers1(self):
        return 'a) 9\t' + 'b) 10\t' + 'c) 11'
    
    def question2(self):
        return '\nQuestion 2. (For lifelines 1, 2 or 3 type the number.)'
    
    def answers2(self):
        return 'here you have answers'
    
    
    def input1(self):
        input1 = input('\nType here:')
        if input1 == 'b)':
            return 'Right answer'
        elif input1 == '1':
            return Lifeline1.q1lifeline1(self)
        elif input1 == '2':
            return Lifeline2.q1lifeline2(self)
        elif input1 == '3':
            return Lifeline3.q1lifeline3(self)            
        else:
            return sys.exit('Wrong answer')
        
    
    def input2(self):
        input2 = input('\nType here:')
        if input2 == 'b)':
            return '\nRight answer'            
        else:
            return sys.exit('Wrong answer')
        
    def input3(self):
        input1 = input('\nType here:')
        if input1 == 'b)':
            return 'Right answer'
        elif input1 == '1':
            return Lifeline1.q2lifeline1(self)
        elif input1 == '2':
            return Lifeline2.q2lifeline2(self)
        elif input1 == '3':
            return Lifeline3.q2lifeline3(self)            
        else:
            return sys.exit('Wrong answer')
        
    def input4(self):
        input4 = input('\nType here:')
        if input4 == 'b)':
            return '\nRight answer'            
        else:
            return sys.exit('Wrong answer')
    
    
        
class Lifeline1:

    def q1lifeline1(self):
        print('\nlifeline 1, quest1')
        return Type.input2(self)
    
    def q2lifeline1(self):
        print('\nlifeline 1, quest2')
        return Type.input4(self)
    
class Lifeline2:

    def q1lifeline2(self):
        print('\nlifeline 2, quest1')
        return Type.input2(self)
    
    def q2lifeline2(self):
        print('\nlifeline 2, quest2')
        return Type.input2(self)

class Lifeline3:

    def q1lifeline3(self):
        print('\nlifeline 3, quest1')
        return Type.input2(self)
    
    def q2lifeline3(self):
        print('\nlifeline 3, quest2')
        return Type.input2(self)



a = Type()

b = Lifeline1()

c = Lifeline2()

d = Lifeline3()

print(a.question1())

print(a.answers1())

print(a.input1())

print(a.question2())

print(a.answers2())

print(a.input3())
```

I want that classes: Lifeline 1, Lifeline 2 and Lifeline 3 could be accessed only once. For instance, if you would access one of them in question 1 then you would not be able to access that class again in question2, etc.

Can someone please help me what should I do to achieve that in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can raise an exception in the `__init__` method if it's called multiple times.

```
class Lifeline1:

    called = False

    def __init__(self):
        if Lifeline1.called:
            raise Exception("Lifeline1 may only be used once")
        Lifeline1.called = True

    def q1lifeline1(self):
        print('\nlifeline 1, quest1')
        return Type.input2(self)
    
    def q2lifeline1(self):
        print('\nlifeline 1, quest2')
        return Type.input4(self)
```

Comment: I tried to run this and I get a NameError:                                                                      NameError: name 'called' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. It should be Lifeline1.called.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. If you call class Lifeline 1 in the 1st question it doesn't raise any exception if you do the same in the 2nd question.

Comment: You should get an error if you do `a = Lifeline1()` and then `b = Lifeline1()`

Comment: Are you trying to prevent it from calling `q1lifeline1()` more than once? You can put a similar check in that method,

Comment: I want to prevent it to call the methods that are inside class Lifeline1 more than once. For instance if a method 'def q1lifeline1(self)' that is inside the class Lifeline1 would be called under Question 1, then a method 'def q2lifeline1(self)', which is under the same class cannot be called under Question 2.

Comment: OK, so do what I just said. Put a check in each message? To avoid having to repeat this, you could define a decorator for it.

Comment: It works now! Thanks! Before, I didn't remove the check from __init__ when I have put it in the methods.